# Hibernate batch update using HQL Query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, batch-processing

I'm using Hibernate for my ORM layer.
I'm try to run batch of HQL queries in one transaction (I cannot use session.update).
The issue is that even the transaction.commit() is at the end of the loop, the update queries run one by one.
Is there a way to run multiple HQL queries in one transaction?

```
public void updateItems() {
    t = session.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
        Query q = createUpdateQuery(session, itemList.get(i));      
        q.executeUpdate(); //updating one by one, and not waiting for transaction commit
    }
    t.commit();
}



Query createUpdateQuery(Session session, Item item) {
    Query q = session.createQuery(
                "Update Item i set i.notes=:notes, i.time=:time, i.counter=:counter, i.status=:status Where i.id=:id and i.time=:time");

    q.setParameter("time", item.getTime());
    q.setParameter("status", item.getStatus());
    q.setParameter("notes", item.getNotes());
    q.setParameter("id", item.getId());
    return q;
}
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code. The updates will occur on the database one by one, but won't be committed until you call commit. You should be able to rollback the transaction at any time before calling commit. This is pretty standard. Are you just worried about the # of round trips to the database?

Comment: Having one transaction does not mean sending multiple updates in big big batch.  And there are simply too many things not looking right in your approach (I wish it is what you are going to do in production code).

Comment: Thanks for you replies.
I need to change from session.update(item) to this approach, and there is a decrease in the performance.

Comment: It seems to me that you are using Hibernate in a way that it is not suitable.  You are supposed to have transaction opened earlier (around the whole business service maybe), get your entities, update the entities directly, and let Hibernate take care of the update when txn is committed.  By doing so, with proper batch size setting, Hibernate will be aware that multiple entities of same type are updated, and make use of JDBC batch operation to update multiple records in DB, for which it reduce number of round trip.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a database transaction to enroll all your statements, but I think you want to use [batch updates](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/).

Just add the following configuration property:

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="10"/>
```

Even so, I think you should use Hibernate to manage the insert/update/delete statements, as you should only focus on [entity state transitions](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-entity-state-transitions/). The [dirty checking mechanism](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-hibernate-dirty-checking/) can automatically detect entities that have been modified, and Hibernate can generate the update statement for you, which is much more convenient.